# Why does it say next(int) has protected access in java.util.Random?

Tags: java, swing, bluej

I'm pretty new to programming and I can't work out for the life of me why I'm receiving the error: "next(int) has protected access in java.util.Random"

Here's the code that the error occurs in...

```
      /**
 * Generates Random Width Multiplier 
 */
public static double randomRMultiplier() { 
   Random randM = new Random();
   double randomMultiplier;

   //Calculates a random value between 12 and 20   
   //(Divided by 10 to make a multiplier)
   do {
      switch(difficultyMark) {
         case 1: 
           randomMultiplier = (randM.next((21-11) + 1) + 11); //Randoms between 11 and 21
           break;

         case 2:
           randomMultiplier = (randM.nextInt((20-12) + 1) + 12); //Randoms between 12 and 20
           break;

         case 3:
           randomMultiplier = (randM.nextInt((19-13) + 1) + 13); //Randoms between 12 and 20
           break;
        }
   } while ( randomMultiplier > 14 & randomMultiplier < 18); //Excludes 15,16,17 as they are too similar to golden values(16-->1.6)

   randomMultiplier = randomMultiplier / 10; //Divide by ten to make decimal multiplies

   return randomMultiplier;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you're meant to be using that directly.

It's actually a "utility" function used by all the *other* `next*` calls, and one that can be over-ridden if you subclass `Random` with a more suitable class, such as something that's not a linear congruential one.

Based on your code, I would suggest that you accidentally used `next` where you intended to use `nextInt`.